# Change font in Container Views UIViewController

Tags: ios, iphone, xcode, uiviewcontroller, uicontainerview

I have a container view within a `UIViewController` (1). How do I change the font of a label in a UIView programatically in the `UIViewController` (2) generated by the container view?

Comment: You can find PLENTY of examples on google

Comment: Thats the thing. I can't. Not for this particular scenario... Accessing a child UIViewController & UIView from within a parent UIViewController.

Answer (score -1):

```
    view.transform = CGAffineTransformMakeScale(1.3, 1.3);
```

Comment: This has nothing to do with the original question.